# Angular2 this.router.navigate fires only once

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have the following tab structure in my page, with it's respective URLs given in braces:

```
           Main Tab (/page)
           /    |    \
          /     |     \
         /      |      \
        /       |       \
Sub Tab 1   Sub Tab 2   Sub Tab 3
(/page/a)   (/page/b)   (/page/c)
```

**Component**

```
@Input() route: string = '';

selectTab(tab) {
  let route = this.router.url.split('?')[0];

  /* Here redirectUrl = "/page/c" */
  if (tab.redirectUrl.length > 0) {
    // console.log(tab.redirectUr); gives /page/c

    this.router.navigate([tab.redirectUrl]);
    // This works but reloads the page and is a very bad idea.
    // window.location.href = tab.redirectUrl;
  }
}
```

**Component.html**

**NOTE:** The actual code has a custom element, I'm showing it as a `<div>` just to show how `redirectUrl` is passed.

```
<div route="/page" [redirectUrl]="/page/c"></div>
```

The `selectTab` function is called when I click **Main Tab**. And since the **Main Tab** has `redirectUrl` the if condition satisfies and the page goes from `/page` to `/page/c`. (**This only works once**)

But, if I click any other **Sub Tab** (say `Sub Tab 2` with URL `/page/b`), then clicking on main tab doesn't redirect to `/page/c`, instead stays at `/page/b`.

I have already checked the `redirectUrl` inside if condition, it's still `/page/c`, but redirection doesn't happen.

What should I do to force redirection?

**EDIT**

@HuseinRoncevic

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)">
```

**EDIT**

**Routes**

```
{
  path: 'page',
  component: MyComponent
},
{
  path: 'page/:action',
  component: MyComponent
}
```

Comment: Could you show how `selectTab()` function is invoked in your HTML partial view?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic Updated

Comment: have you used parent path in routes? @Abhi

Comment: @AmeePrajapati I hope you are asking about `/path` and it's defined in the route as `path: 'page/:action'`

Comment: @Abhi I just created a project that would sort of work in the way I understood from your question. i can change routes without any problems. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic There are no errors

Comment: Let me write an answer based on the project that I created so that I could try to figure out where your problem might be. I hope it would end up being an answer as I would like to pollute the question with wrong answers.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic I added my routes, may be it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your route definition points to the same component:

```
{
    path: 'page',
    component: MyComponent
},
{
    path: 'page/:action',
    component: MyComponent
}
```

Why don't you create a separate component for `page/:action` route?

Here is something from the [Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse)  documentation on Angular.io.

> Observable paramMap and component reuse
>   In this example, you retrieve the route parameter map from an Observable. That implies that the route parameter map can change during the lifetime of this component.
>
> They might. By default, the router re-uses a component instance when it re-navigates to the same component type without visiting a different component first. The route parameters could change each time.

I believe that this is your issue. You are not really changing the components. Rather, you are reusing the same component over and over again. And for that reason router is reusing the same component instance.

For that reason I would create a new component that handles the `:action` part of your route.

```
{
    path: 'page',
    component: MyComponent
},
{
    path: 'page/:action',
    component: IHandleActionPartHereComponent
}
```

#### Update

In your `selectTab()` function, what is the purpose of splitting along the question mark?

```
let route = this.router.url.split('?')[0];
```

Your route will not be appended as a query parameter, but rather it will be appended to the actual route as in `http://something/page/a` not `http://something/?page/b` or however you imagined this. The `url` property will return the url as determined by the router: `/page/a` or `/page/b`. The length of your result should be 0. Because of that your `if` part will always be false and no redirection will occur.

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of complex. I can't use any other component. And in the same component different tabs are distinguished by their routes. Just want to know, how can I force redirection with `router.navigate` or any other way

Comment: Do you have `ngOnInit()` in your MyComponent that is reading the action parameter? Also, how is the base route different from the one that has :action parameter? How does a user know that you are presenting different content?

Comment: No, I don't see `ngOnInit()` block in component. Each tab has a @input called route(eg: page/a) and it's matched against current URL (`let route = this.router.url.split('?')[0];`). If `tab.route === route`

Comment: Unless you introduce one more component, register it in the routes table, I am not sure that you'll be able to do much. There might be some workaround, but I have not met it yet. On the other hand, what is the idea of using the same component for /page and /page/a or b or c? How is the result distinguished between different parameters

Comment: @Abhi, where in your code do you perform `tab.route === route` check?

Comment: It's just one more method in the component that also calls `selectTab(tab)` when the above condition matches

Comment: Thanks for your idea of having different components for different tabs.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
{ path: 'page', component: PageParentComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'a', pathMatch: 'full'},
          { path: 'a', component: AComponent},
          { path: 'b', component: BComponent}
        ]
 }
```

in HTML

```
this.router.navigate(['page/a']); // or
this.router.navigate(['page/b']);
```

Comment: +1 for the concept, but sadly I can't hardcode `redirectTo` in routes, it's kind of needs to be dynamically decided