# URL in browser doesnt change when navigate with the route parameters in Angular4

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing

I have following routes defined for .Net core angular app.
When I navigate to the `project-form/:id`, it's going to the page but the URL doesn't change in the browser, it just stays on the current page URL.

```
{ path: 'project-form', component: ProjectFormComponent },
{ path: 'project-form/:id', component: ProjectFormComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'dt-instance', component: DtInstanceComponent },
{ path: 'project-dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 this.router.navigate fires only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486666/angular2-this-router-navigate-fires-only-once)

Comment: The router is using the same route. Apparently this is not a bug but a feature. You'd have to look into https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy to ask Angular not to reuse your routes.